# groupby and assign value based on condition

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe containing the relationship of id and its parent and some code.

```
child_id        parent_id   code 
111             null        SS2
222             111         SS1
333             222         ZZZ
444             222         ZZZ
555             888         TTT
666             777         AAA
777             222         SS1
888             222         SS1
999             111         SS2
```

I'm trying to create a dataframe  where I'd have parent_id and a code based on condition if number of children_ids with the same code as parent  code is at least 50% then parent code is assigned, if not it's empty.

```
parent_id   code  final_code
222         SS1          SS1
111         SS2          SS2
888         SS1          NULL
777         SS1          NULL
```

for **parent_id = 222**  there are children 333 with code ZZZ, 444 with code ZZZ, 777 with code SS1, 888 with code SS ( 2 matching to parent code and 2 non-matching - assign parent code);

for **parent_id=111** there are children 222 with code SS1, and 999 with code SS2 (one child with the same parent code, assign parent code),

for **parent_id  = 888**, there's one child 555 with code TTT (parent code doesn't match child code - none is assigned),

for **parent_id - 777** , child code is AAA , which doesn't match parent code - none assigned

My understanding that the approach is to use groupby

e.g `df.groupby('parent_id)` which would produce the groups with some comparison of code within a group and the parent's code

any tips are much appreciated

***Additional Clarification.***  in a dataframe every **child_id** has a **code** and in most cases some ***parent,*** which is some id from  **child_id** column. Column **parent_id** 'shows' relationships between children

Comment: where is the parent_code column?

Comment: apologies it's confusing naming. I'll update the question description

Comment: Hi, for parent_id == 222, code is either SS1 or ZZZ. So, how do you know that parent code is SS1 and not ZZZ? Do you have a table of parent_id and parent_code relationships?